# как создать переменную TextStyle?

Tags: flutter, dart

Как создать переменную TextStyle и возможно ли такое?

Пример кода обычный

```
Text(
 'Hello World!',
 style: TextStyle(
  color: Colors.deepPurple,
  fontSize: 18.0
 ),
),
```

Пример кода с переменной TextStyle, который генерирует ошибку

```
//объявляем переменную или поле класса
TextStyle _textStyle1;

@override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
   //инициализируем переменную
   _textStyle1 = TextStyle(
    color: Colors.deepPurple,
    fontSize: 18.0
 );
}

Text(
 'Hello World!',
 //генерируется ошибка
 style: _textStyle1,
),
```

Возможно создавать такую переменную или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все работает... Проверить можно в [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  TextStyle _textStyle1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _textStyle1 = TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple, fontSize: 18.0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Hello World!',
          style: _textStyle1,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Уважаемый MiT, спасибо Вам!

Comment: @Anton эмм, я как-бы код не исправлял и вставил ваш пример... Ну ладно, пожалуйста!)